# Can't get the value of a selected element from a dynamic data list (only getting the last element)

Tags: javascript, html

Context: I have a list with 500+ tickers that I'm retrieving from MySQL, but when I select a ticker, I can only get the value of the last ticker (which is TWTR) and not the selected value. The goal with this is to pass this data to an array of objects where `x` is the ticker name

HTML:

```
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <input style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);border-radius: 10px; border: none;  text-align: center;" list="brow">
        <datalist id="brow">
          <select name="selectStock" class="selectStock" id="selectStock">
            <option></option>
          </select>
        </datalist>
        <input class="button1" onclick=" send();" value="Add Stock"></input>
        <!-- <input class="button1" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="send();"></input> -->
      </form>
```

Javascript:

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectStock");
    var options = <?php echo json_encode($tickerArray) ?>; 

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      var opt = options[i]; 
      var el = document.createElement("option");
      el.innerHTML = opt;
      el.value = opt; 
      select.appendChild(el); 
    }

var open = <?php echo json_encode($openPrices) ?>;

    var selected = []


    function send() {

      selected = [
        ...selected,
        {
          "x": el.value, //The goal is to pass the tickers added/selected here, creating multiple objects inside of this array where each time adds a new stock, it gets added as a new object. As of now, I keep getting the last array which is TWTR
          "y": 1.2 
        }
      ]
```

This is the data structure of the variable `options` (the list the user can select from):

```
var options = [["A"],["AAL"],["AAP"],["AAPL"],["ABBV"],["ABC"]...,["TWTR"]]
```

This is the data structure of the variable `selected` when I press `Add Stock` button 3 times:

```
[
    {
        "x": "TWTR",
        "y": 1.2
    },
    {
        "x": "TWTR",
        "y": 1.2
    },
    {
        "x": "TWTR",
        "y": 1.2
    }
]
```

Any help is very welcome!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>


<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <form>
        <input style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);border-radius: 10px; border: none;  text-align: center;" list="brow">
        <datalist id="brow">
                  <select name="selectStock" id="selectStock">
                  </select>
                </datalist>
        <input class="button1" onclick=" send();" value="Add Stock"></input>

      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("selectStock");
  var options = [
    ["A"],
    ["AAL"],
    ["AAP"],
    ["AAPL"],
    ["ABBV"],
    ["ABC"],
    ["TWTR"]
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.innerHTML = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    dropdown.appendChild(el);
  }

  var selected = []

  function send() {
    console.log(dropdown.value)
console.log(selected)

    selected.push({
      x: dropdown.value,
      y: 1.2,
    });
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Not related to the problem, but `send()` should just use selected.push()` rather than copying the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `<datalist>`, you don't use `<select>`. The value of the datalist is in the associated `<input>`.

In your snippet, the style of the input makes it impossible for the user to selet something from it.

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementById("selectStock");
var input = document.getElementById("brow");
var options = [
  ["A"],
  ["AAL"],
  ["AAP"],
  ["AAPL"],
  ["ABBV"],
  ["ABC"],
  ["TWTR"]
];

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var opt = options[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.innerHTML = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  dropdown.appendChild(el);
}

var selected = []

function send() {
  selected.push({
    x: brow.value,
    y: 1.2,
  });
  console.log(selected);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>


<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <form>
        <input id="brow" list="selectStock">
        <datalist id="selectStock">
        </datalist>
        <input class="button1" onclick=" send();" value="Add Stock"></input>

      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the input! I am now getting an empty string by doing this instead of the last element, however. By setting `el` to the dropdown do you mean passing the dropdown.value to el? (I'm using `select` instead of `dropdown` in the example)

Comment: Yes, I renamed the variable in my version.

Comment: I had a typo, `dropdon` for `dropdown`

Comment: I keep getting an empty string back with this implementation, not sure why

Comment: I can't see any reason for that. What does `console.log(dropdown.value)` show?

Comment: I get nothing in return when doing that. Doing console.log to `opt`  and `el. value` retrieves the last element (TWTR). Doing console log in `selected` results in this object: `{
    "x": "",
    "y": 1.2
}`

Comment: Can you edit the question and add a [mre] using the [Stack Snippet] feature?

Comment: Added the snippet to the code above. Also, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: It is odd because when I do `console.log(dropdown)` I can see the created options but when doing dropdown.value it returns empty. It's as if it is not seeing which option is being clicked/selected and then added to the variable selected by using the send() function

Comment: I was thinking in doing something like `opt.setAttribute ("selected", clicked);` where clicked = True. That way everytime the user clicks on an option the attribute would turn to selected? Would that be a thing? Not sure

Comment: The `dropdown.value` is essentially retrieving the first option. In my example, I have an empty option and that's why I keep getting empty value. I removed that empty value and I now get the value of the first created option (which is "A"), but I still can't get the selected stock